# How can I set the JWT token to be unique for each user

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, security, spring-security, jwt

I implemented a JWT authentication service, the process works fine and I get the jwt token back as a response for each authentication. The problem is that when trying to access another endpoint that requires authentication, any token I get for user1 works for other users, meaning for example when trying to get data about a user1's profile, using another user's jwt auth token I can get user1's data when he didn't even authenticate.
I tried to add the user's claims whenever generating the token but the problem is still the same.
here's the **JwtAuthenticationFilter** class:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt_token;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt_token = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUserEmail(jwt_token); // extract userEmail from JWT token
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt_token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
            else {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized");
                return;
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and here's the **JwtService** class:

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    //constant secret key that must change
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "C:\\Users\\ihebt\\Documents\\security\\security\\src\\main\\resources/private.key";

/*    public JwtService(CustomLoginSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler, CustomLoginFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
    }*/

    public String extractUserEmail(String jwtToken) {
        return extractClaim(jwtToken, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("email", userDetails.getUsername());

        return generateToken(claims, userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply((claims));
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String useremail = extractUserEmail(token);
        return (useremail.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String jwt_token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt_token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        try {
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH));
            return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(privateKeyBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read private key file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to decode the jwt token and extract the username (you can encode that data in the token itself) and not allow user1 to access anything from user2, you have to program this check yourself. And make sure only user1 can generate a token with 'user1' as the name. https://jwt.io/